# How to pass multiple parameters values from one php page to another

Tags: php

Below is the setup I am using:

I have this button(submit):

```
<input  type="submit" name="pageaction" class="contact_list_uploadcsv_btn" value="Send SMS"  />
```

pageaction: is a switch case"Send SMS" in the controller.php, so when the user press "Send SMS" it will perform the case"Send SMS".There are some parameter in this page templates.php which I want to redirect them to Sendsms.php page when the user press "Send SMS button".

So I have templates.php which contain the button and the fields(values) that I want to take them to Sendsms.php. Controller.php linking between the two pages templates.php and Sendssms.php

The fields in template.php are :

```
<div class="contacts_checkbox_02"><input name="template_id" id="template_id" type="checkbox"  value="'.$templates_row['template_id'].'" style="margin-top:0px;" /></div>

<div class="search_title01" id="title">'.$templates_row['title'].'</div>

<div class="message_body01" id="body">'.$templates_row['body'].'</div>
```

When the user check the checkbox and press "Send SMS" it should redirect him to "Sendsms.php" and pass the the values of [title] and [body].

Could you please help with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one `<input type="hidden"` for title and one for body. And set form's `action="Sendsms.php"` and it should do what you want.

Comment: How I can pass parameter if I use this code of the button:   <a href="?action=sms"><input  type="button" class="contact_list_uploadcsv_btn" value="Send SMS"  /></a>

Comment: data from input fields will only be passed if the fields are inside the `<form>` tag and if the form is submited, for example with `<input type="submit">`

Comment: <form action="?action=sms" method='post'>
                                        <input  type="submit" class="contact_list_uploadcsv_btn" value="Send SMS"  />
                                        
                                        <input type="hidden" name="template_id" value="<?print $_POST['template_id'];?>" class="text">
                                       
                                        
                                        </form>

Comment: I couldn't get value of $_POST['template_id'] because it is in another form in the same page, how to get it's value from the other form?

Comment: Only with javascript. But it's a better idea to have one form for the task.